# PowerShell not processing arguments correctly at least I think so?

Tags: powershell

I've written this code to format Flash Drives:

```
[CmdLetBinding()]

Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $DrvLtr,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [ ValidateSet("NTFS","ReFS","exFAT",
                  "FAT32","FAT")]
    [String] $FileSys = "NTFS" ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [Switch] $TestIt
)

$FVArgs = @{DriveLetter = $DrvLtr
            FileSystem  = $FileSys
            Force       = $True
            Full        = $True
            Confirm     = $True
            WhatIf      = $($TestIt.isPresent)
           }

 Format-Volume @FVArgs
```

When I call the code as follows:

```
PS> .\Dev-New-Format-FlashDrive.ps1 -TestIt -DrvLtr x
```

It runs as though the -TestIt (value for -WhatIf) and -Confirm parameters to Format-Volume don't exist. The Format-Volume is processed and the drive is formatted.

I ran the code with a break-point at the Volume-Format line and tested the parameters with the following results:

```
PS> .\Dev-New-Format-FlashDrive.ps1 -TestIt -DrvLtr x

Hit Line breakpoint on 'G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Dev-New-Format-FlashDrive.ps1:24'
PS> $FVArgs

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
FileSystem                     NTFS                                            
Force                          True                                            
Confirm                        True                                            
WhatIf                         True                                            
DriveLetter                    x                                               
Full                           True                                            

PS>
```

Ideas?

Edited:
Theo, in response to your post:

```
Test Results:

PS> .\Test\Test-Format-FlashDriveOrdered.ps1 -DrvLtr "X" -FileSys FAT32 -TestIt

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatu
                                                               s               
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------
X                        FAT32          Removable Healthy      OK              

PS> .\Test\Test-Format-FlashDriveMovedSwitches.ps1 -DrvLtr "X" -FileSys FAT32 -TestIt

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatu
                                                               s               
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------
X                        FAT32          Removable Healthy      OK              

# Force set to False on all the following...

# WhatIf Removed
PS> .\Test\Test-Format-FlashDrive.ps1 -DrvLtr "X" -FileSys FAT32 -TestIt1
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatu
                                                               s               
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------
X                        FAT32          Removable Healthy      OK              


# Whatif Replaced Confirm Removed
PS> .\Test\Test-Format-FlashDrive.ps1 -DrvLtr "X" -FileSys FAT32 -TestIt

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatu
                                                               s               
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------
X                        FAT32          Removable Healthy      OK
```

Comment: I don't think it's an argument processing thing; looks like you're not the only person finding that `Format-Volume -WhatIf` just doesn't work; [link1](https://twitter.com/bielawb/status/1197845978998562817) and [link2](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/35049037-format-volume-whatif) and [link3](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf2056c9-a43a-4818-a67a-dd26eb477ba8/formatvolume-and-whatif-the-whatif-does-work-)

Comment: Thanks. Now why didn't the -Confirm switch work?

Comment: Maybe our powershell pops (*mklement*) can shine some light/insight on this issue. Glad I seen this before trying it out myself!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, I merely want to know more about this, so kindly, could you tell us what happens in the following scenarios:

About the [Confirm switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/whatif-confirm-and-validateonly-switches-exchange-2013-help#confirm-switch)

By default, the Shell automatically applies the Confirm switch to cmdlets that have the following verbs:

**Clear,  Disable,  Dismount,  Move , Remove,  Stop,  Suspend,  Uninstall**

`Format` seems not to be among those..
The page also states that *"If you want to manually apply the Confirm switch to a command, include the Confirm switch **at the end of the command**"*

Almost the same goes for the [WhatIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/whatif-confirm-and-validateonly-switches-exchange-2013-help#whatif-switch) switch:
Again *"When you run a command together with the WhatIf switch, you put the WhatIf switch **at the end of the command**"*

This to me could imply that you cannot use these switches in a splatting Hashtable (??)

Out of curiousity, what happens if you try

```
[CmdLetBinding()]

Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $DrvLtr,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [ ValidateSet("NTFS","ReFS","exFAT","FAT32","FAT")]
    [String] $FileSys = "NTFS" ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [Switch] $TestIt
)

# try with an [ordered] hash, so the Confirm and WhatIf switches are last
$FVArgs = [ordered]@{
    DriveLetter = $DrvLtr
    FileSystem  = $FileSys
    Force       = $True
    Full        = $True
    Confirm     = $True
    WhatIf      = $($TestIt.isPresent)
}

Format-Volume @FVArgs
```

And what happens if you take them out of the splatting hashtable like:

```
[CmdLetBinding()]

Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $DrvLtr,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [ ValidateSet("NTFS","ReFS","exFAT","FAT32","FAT")]
    [String] $FileSys = "NTFS" ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [Switch] $TestIt
)

$FVArgs = @{
    DriveLetter = $DrvLtr
    FileSystem  = $FileSys
    Force       = $True
    Full        = $True
}

Format-Volume @FVArgs -Confirm -WhatIf:($TestIt.isPresent)
```

Comment: Theo, see edited question for my test results. Seems nothing works!

Comment: @RetiredGeek Wow... Thanks for testing all that. Sems a real buggy cmdlet..